# Why is my PATH environment variable duplicated

Tags: windows, windows-7, environment-variables, administration

I am using windows 7 and I have a user account (not admin).
Strangely my PATH looks like it is duplicated from the PATH of the admin session...

```
C:\MyPgm\Console2>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;

****here it is the same stuff again

C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
```

I looked on the admin session and the path looks fine. When I do `regedit>HKEY CURRENT USER>Environment>PATH` the variable is fine and not duplicated.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: The PATH environment variable is built by appending the machine PATH to the user PATH.  If everything in the user PATH is also in the machine PATH, then you can delete the user PATH altogether.

Comment: Good ! do you know what key it is so I can check ? Also you might want to make it an answer !

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment but you can also find this information under "Advanced System Settings" in the System control panel.

Comment: Run => %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables